# How to convert a list of tensors of dim N to a tensor of dim N+1

Tags: tensorflow

I need to convert a list of tensors of dimensionality N to a new tensor with dimensionality N+1 so that the new dimension would be the right most dimension.

For example if x and y would be tensors of shape (4,3) both then I am trying to create a new tensor z of shape (4,3,2) by forming z and setting tensor x as the 0th element along the third dimension and setting tensor y as the 1st element along the third dimension. In pseudocode:

```
z = tf.fromList([x,y],3)
```

What's the best way to do that in Tensorflow. I was unable to figure it out from the documentation of TF 0.7.1.

Answer (score 12):

If I'm reading you correctly, you want to *interleave* the data of the two tensors.

You want to `tf.pack()` them together, which would form a tensor of shape `[2, 4, 3]` and then `tf.transpose([1, 2, 0])` that resulting tensor to get to the interleaving you want.

Comment: It appears that [`tf.pack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#pack) now takes a parameter for the axis on which you want the interleaving to occur; for this case, I believe you can use `tf.pack(my_list, axis=2)`.

Answer (score 12):

dga's method works, but `tf.pack()` has been removed from TensorFlow V1.0 onwards.

You can use `tf.stack()` to achieve the same.

Docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack

Comment: Can I set tf.identity of a stack? Could it work to output results in session.run?